# How to get equal numer in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have to find in array-pole number - x and return index(in it is on first the 0, second 1 ...). In SASM it stops in for loop and gives me SEG foult. How can I fix it?
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

````
section .data
pole dd 1,2,8,0,
x dd 8

section .text


CMAIN:        
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    
    mov edx, [x] 
    mov ebx, pole
    push ebx

    call find_equal
    add esp, 4
    
    call WriteInt32
    pop ebp
    ret
  
 fac:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [esp+8]
    mov ebx, eax
    jmp .for
    .for:
    dec ebx
    mul ebx
    cmp ebx, 1
    je .end
    jmp .for
    
    .end:
     pop ebp
     ret 
     
find_equal:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ecx, [esp+8] ; pole
    mov eax, 0
    
    jmp .for1
    
    .for1:
        mov ecx, [ecx]
        cmp edx, ecx
        je .end1
        inc eax
        mov ecx, [ecx+4*eax]
        jmp .for1
        
        
        
    .end1:
     pop ebp
     ret 
     ```
````

Comment: Start by [debugging](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/nasm.shtml) your program so you can understand what's happening (look at register contents and memory for each line you execute and compare your expectations to reality), then trace it back to where the problem comes from and fix it.

Comment: `mov ecx, [ecx]`  here you overwrite ECX with the value of its pointer.  `mov ecx, [ecx+4*eax]`  here this seems to expect that ECX still has its base pointer value.... so you need to save the base pointer somewhere and dereference that instead.  You're using ECX for two different things (holding a pointer for dereferencing and holding a value for comparison) but you don't take care to make sure that the correct one is in the register when it's supposed to be.

Comment: Well it still gives me segfault on line mov ecx, [ecx] when it is called for second time